# CMD Pass double quotes with equal signs with outer double quotes as a parameter

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Thanks for concern. The case is like:

```
[ffm.bat]
rem %0 in "options" out
set opt=%2
set opt=%opt:~1,-1%&rem de-quotes
set ffcmdstr=ffmpeg -i "%~1" %2 "%~3"
```

if I want the `ffcmdstr` variable to be set to the following:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mpg -vf "hqdn3d=0:0:4:0" -c:v h264 out.mp4
```

ideally I'd enter:

```
ffm.bat in.mpg "-vf "hqdn3d=0:0:4:0" -c:v h264" out.mp4
```

problem:

1. space is a delimiter, so I use "..."
2. = is a delimiter, too; fine within "..." but
3. " is also needed within "..." then cause space breaks the parameter again.

Tried several ESCAPE ways but failed.
Please give me any useful thoughts.

Now I use:

```
"-vf 'hqdn3d=0:0:4:0' -c:v h264"
```

and add a substitution:

```
set opt=%opt:'="%
```

Comment: I recommend a different method of commenting. Using REM on the same line as another command is very messy. I would just use `:: comment` on the line before the command you are commenting on - or even `REM comment`.

Comment: I suggest that your method of using single quotes, then substituting for double quotes is the best method. However, do you actually need to substitute out the single quotes? Can you still call the ffmpeg command with switch values in single quotes?

Comment: @unclemeat, the comment after that execution is for you helpers but thanks. Unfortunately whether ffmpeg accepts single quotes or not, this cmd string is not accepted by COMMAND.COM of Win. And it causes ffmpeg error: 
1.
`[NULL @ 0000000004bb96a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -vf 'hq
n3d=0:0:4:0' -c:v h264'`
2.
`-vf 'hqdn3d=0:0:4:0' -c:v h264: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CALL :gffmpeg "in.mpg -vf "hqdn3d=0:0:4:0" -c:v h264 out.mp4"
CALL :gffmpeg2 in.mpg "-vf "hqdn3d=0:0:4:0" -c:v h264" out.mp4
GOTO :eof

:gffmpeg
SET "params=%*"
ECHO ffmpeg -i %params:~1,-1%
GOTO :EOF

:gffmpeg2
SET "params=%*"
SET parm1=%~1
:parml
SHIFT
SET "parmlast=%~2"
IF DEFINED parmlast GOTO parml
SET "parmlast=%~1"

SET "parm=%parm1%"
:parm1L
IF DEFINED parm SET "parm=%parm:~1%"&SET "params=%params:~1%"&GOTO parm1L

SET "parm=%parmlast%"
:parmLL
IF DEFINED parm SET "parm=%parm:~1%"&SET "params=%params:~0,-1%"&GOTO parmLL

ECHO ffmpeg -i %parm1% %params:~2,-2% %parmlast%
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's two ways - the first requires a reformatting of your parameter-supplied; the second as you've currently got it.

---

So, taking the second method step-by-step:

Driving the batch with *thisbatch* in.mpg "-vf "hqdn3d=0:0:4:0" -c:v h264" out.mp4

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "params=%*"
SET parm1=%~1
:parml
SHIFT
SET "parmlast=%~2"
IF DEFINED parmlast GOTO parml
SET "parmlast=%~1"

SET "parm=%parm1%"
:parm1L
IF DEFINED parm SET "parm=%parm:~1%"&SET "params=%params:~1%"&GOTO parm1L

SET "parm=%parmlast%"
:parmLL
IF DEFINED parm SET "parm=%parm:~1%"&SET "params=%params:~0,-1%"&GOTO parmLL

ECHO ffmpeg -i %parm1% %params:~2,-2% %parmlast%
GOTO :EOF
```

First, set `params` to the entire command-tail `in.mpg "-vf "hqdn3d=0:0:4:0" -c:v h264" out.mp4` (the quotes in the `set` command ensure that trailing spaces on the line are **not** included in the value assigned to the variable.)

Set `parm1` to the first of these parameters, with the quotes removed if they are present (the `~` does this) so `parm1` becomes `in.mpg`.

Next we have a loop which

- "shifts" the parameters' positions : #1 is dropped, #2 becomes #1 and
  so on.
- sets `parmlast` to the resultant #2 parameter.
- checks to see whether `parmlast` has a value. If it has, keep shifting until it hasn't.

`%1` must now have the last parameter, so assign it to `parmlast` and remove any quotes. `parmlast` gets the value `out.mp4`.

make `parm` have the same value as `parm1` so `in.mpg`

Now another loop. Remove the first character of `parm` and of `params` until `parm` is empty. This removes `in.mpg` from `params` so `params` becomes `"-vf "hqdn3d=0:0:4:0" -c:v h264" out.mp4`

Next, pull a similar trick, this time using `paramlast` to remove `out.mp4` from the *end* of `params`. `params` becomes `"-vf "hqdn3d=0:0:4:0" -c:v h264"`

Final step - echo the required `ffmpeg` line with the `-i` switch, the value of `parm1`, the string from `params` minus the first 2 and last 2 characters (<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> respectively) and apply the last parameter from `parmlast`.

Comment: [gffmpeg]
  
  `%*="in.mpg -vf "hqdn3d=0:0:4:0" -c:v h264 out.mp4"`  
  
  `%0=:gffmpeg`  

  `%1="in.mpg -vf "hqdn3d`  

  `%2=0:0:4:0" -c:v h264 out.mp4"`  

  `%3=`  

%4=
%5=
%6=
%7=
%8=
%9=

Comment: I'm still studying the 2nd method of your answer. The only thing I learned is that words sided by a parameter within double quotes are taken as the same parameter. `echo.%%*=%params%`  `for /l %%n in (0,1,9) do (`  `call set _pn=%%%%%%n`  `call echo.%%%%%%n=!_pn!`  `)`